# Hbase several puts with identical row keys and identifier

Tags: hbase

I am working on a multithreaded application..

my application can run put command based on row key value..therefore, the put command can be executed for an identical key value several times. does this cause an exception in habse?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. Hbase operations are atomic on a single rowkey. So multiple updates on a key will be executed one by one. If you put same rowkey+column family+column key with different values, it will override values until last one. Also if you enable versioning on column family, you can store every update value.